# Umbraco - reset admin password

Tags: umbraco7

Is it possible? I was playing around with Umbraco, got it started up last week (just got it up and running, didn't do anything beyond that) and by Monday I'd forgotten the password. I looked [here](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/4790-ouch-forgot-admin-password-how-to-reset?p=2), but none of the suggestions seem to work. Changing the membership provider to `Clear` here:

```
    <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.MembersMembershipProvider, Umbraco" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="8" useLegacyEncoding="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Member" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
    <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.UsersMembershipProvider, Umbraco" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="8" useLegacyEncoding="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
```

If I change `UmbracoMembershipProvider` to `Clear`, it doesn't seem to do anything. If I change `UserMembershipProvider` to `Clear` then the whole site breaks (it complains that you can only use Umbraco with ASP.NET identity if it's set to `Hashed`).

All the suggested hashes to replace the `userPassword` don't seem to work. Setting the `userPassword` to an empty string doesn't work because the UI won't allow an empty string as a password, and the backend will check it and complain too.

Is there any simple, fool-proof way to reset the damn thing without uninstalling and starting over?

Comment: are you maybe loggin in with a username instead of an email account?

Comment: I think the "Clear" hack only works on older versions of Umbraco (probably Umbraco 7.2 and before).

Answer (score 10):

We had this issue receiving an Umbraco install from a 3rd party but no credentials.  **This is for Umbraco 7.6.1**

•   Modify UsersMembershipProvider set useLegacyEncoding="true" In web.config then restart iis

- use the usual script to set the admin password the old way

  UPDATE umbracoUser set userdisabled=0, userNoConsole=0, userLogin='admin', failedLoginAttempts=0, userPassword='bnWxWyFdCueCcKrqniYK9iAS+7E=' where id=0

•   Log in as admin/default

•   Navigate to the admin user

•   Modify UsersMembershipProvider set useLegacyEncoding="false" then restart iis again

•   CTRL-F5 to reload web.config (you should still be logged in via cookie)

•   Select “Change Your Password”

•   Check the “Reset Password” checkbox

•   Click Save

•   You will get a green dialog with the new password

•   Copy the new password to clipboard

•   Click “Change Password” again

•   Paste into the “Current Password” field

•   Enter admin123456 as new password

•   Enter admin123456 as confirm password

•   Click Save

To check restart iis, log in as admin/admin123456

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE umbracoUser set userdisabled=0, userLogin='admin', userPassword='bnWxWyFdCueCcKrqniYK9iAS+7E=' where id=0
```

hash is "default" without the quotes

Comment: You should add some explanation to improve the quality of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

For Umbraco 7-8, create a class as below:

```
using System.Web.Security;
using Umbraco.Core.Composing;
using Umbraco.Core;
using Umbraco.Core.Services;
using Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers;

namespace Test
{
    [RuntimeLevel(MinLevel = RuntimeLevel.Run)]
    public class StartingComposer : IUserComposer
    {
        public void Compose(Composition composition)
        {
            composition.Components().Append<StartingEvent>();
        }
    }
    public class StartingEvent : IComponent
    {
        private readonly IUserService _userService; 
        public StartingEvent(IUserService userService)
        {
            _userService = userService;
            var adminUser = _userService.GetUserById(-1);
            adminUser.Username = adminUser.Email = "admin@gmail.com";
            adminUser.FailedPasswordAttempts = 0;
            adminUser.IsLockedOut = false;
            adminUser.IsApproved = true;
            adminUser.RawPasswordValue = (Membership.Providers["UsersMembershipProvider"] as UsersMembershipProvider)?.HashPasswordForStorage("Admin123*");
            userService.Save(adminUser);
        }
        public void Initialize()
        {
        }
        public void Terminate()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me, although I created an Umbraco Eventhandler for this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the database it is pointing to? If you do, you can reset the password this way.

```
UPDATE umbracoUser set userdisabled=0, userLogin='admin', userPassword='rboj46J1NSyvbZ5c7UI/5+m+Pcc=' where id=0
```

or

```
UPDATE umbracoUser set userdisabled=0, userLogin='admin', userPassword='default' where id=0
```

Where the user is `admin` and the password is updated to `default`.

Comment: Tried the first one and it doesn't work for me. The second one would only work if I could switch to clear instead of hashed passwords, but changing that in web.config doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try using `userPassword=''` and then try to log in and it should prompt a reset. Or try going to your SQL gui and click the box and try updating it that way.

Comment: You can't log in with a blank password. The front-end checks it as does the backend. Blank passwords are rejected.

Comment: Are you sure? I've read multiple solutions and tested on Umbraco 5 (out of date I know). I would try anyway, if not looks like a reinstall would be your best bet.

Comment: Or you could try to make a new user with privileges and trigger a reset for admin.

Comment: I can't make a new user when I can't get in at all.

Comment: I would need to be able to generate a password hash that worked to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem the other day.
`bnWxWyFdCueCcKrqniYK9iAS+7E=` should be the correct hash for `default`.

Insert this in the DB, restart the application (you can just download, and then upload the web.config at the root), and now login with your username and `default` as password.

When you are logged in you can change the password, and everything should be fine. :)

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To everyone who is unable to solve this using the steps above, what you can do is copy the password from another Umbraco.sdf database file and paste it over the current password in the new sites Umbraco.sdf file. Then log in using that password. You may have to clear cache and reload the site.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to update the column **lastLockoutDate** as well for this manual update in database to work.

Try the following query to update password of **admin** user as **default** :

```
UPDATE [dbo].umbracoUser set userdisabled=0, userLogin='admin', userPassword='bnWxWyFdCueCcKrqniYK9iAS+7E=', lastLockoutDate = null where id=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Umbraco 8 or higher or any other version.

Create a new project in visual studio, install the version of umbraco you want (same as your original project) (using nuget).

Do the setup on the DB type and version (same as your db of your lost account) you want. This time, write down your credentials you want to use.

After the basic installation go to the table [DATABASENAME].[dbo].[umbracoUser] and create a update query of your account, with the info of your new DB.

```
UPDATE umbracoUser 
set userdisabled=0, 
    userNoConsole=0, 
    userEmail='admin@admin.com', 
    userLogin='admin@admin.com',
    failedLoginAttempts=0,  
    userPassword='[COPY HASHED PASSWORD]',
    securityStampToken = '[COPY securityStampToken]'   
where id=-1 -- for version 8.* it is -1
```

And now you can login to your project without stopping,resetting or changing your original project

Answer (score 0):

For Umbraco 8, I followed **Bunkerbuster**'s answer above but was still having problems.

I found I had to sync the machineKey settings between the temporary/dummy site's Web.config and the forgotten password site's Web.config.

The configuration block looks like this:

```
 <machineKey validationKey="xxx"
             decryptionKey="xxx"
             validation="HMACSHA256"
             decryption="AES" />
```